# is there equivalent command of whoami(linux command) for mongo cli?

Tags: mongodb

I cannot believe I cannot find this command.. I want to confirm who I am as logged in from cli and I want to see what my roles are(show roles.. but I wanted to confirm what user I am logged in before issuing that command. is there no equivalent command in mongodb??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [connectionStatus](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/connectionStatus/index.html#connectionstatus) database command can tell you that:

```
db.runCommand( { connectionStatus: 1, showPrivileges: true } )
```

From the doc, part of that return is:

> **connectionStatus.authInfo**
>
> A document with data about the authentication state of the current connection, including users and available permissions.

Comment: great thank you and accepted.  However, is there way to alias that to something shorter? Why not have simple command like `id` or `whoami` is beyond me

Comment: You could run `db.runCommand("connectionStatus")` to get just the default output.